# Using a NONE value in an Enum instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, enums

I'm just wondering about this because I've seen it a couple time in code. Checking for undefined in an typescript enum can sometimes cause unexpected behaviour like in this example.

```
  enum DoSomething {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3,
  }
  function doSomething(doSomething?: DoSomething): void {
    if (doSomething) {
      console.log('do something')
    } else {
      console.log('do nothing')
    }
  }
  doSomething(undefined) // -> do nothing
  doSomething(DoSomething.VALUE1) // -> do nothing
  doSomething(DoSomething.VALUE2) // -> do something
```

This is of course because the VALUE1 of the enum is actually 0. Could it make sense to use something like NONE in the first position of a enum and not allowing undefined to prevent others from running into this?

```
  enum DoSomething {
    NONE,
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3,
  }
  function doSomething(doSomething: DoSomething): void {
    if (doSomething) {
      console.log('do something')
    } else {
      console.log('do nothing')
    }
  }
  doSomething(DoSomething.NONE) // -> do nothing
  doSomething(DoSomething.VALUE1) // -> do something
  doSomething(DoSomething.VALUE2) // -> do something
```

I mean of course you could always just check for undefined explicitly ... But if you didn't think about the if(0) it could take some time to figure out the mistake as it only fails for the first value of the enum. Any thoughts / input?

Comment: A good testing suite would've probably captured such mistake :)

Comment: You could also assign values other than the defaults to your enums so that they're not falsy`enum DoSomething { VALUE1 = 1543 }`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is basically about code conventions, which can also depend on the company you work for.
Your example is too abstract, and violates code convention that is not dependent on company.

As you said, depending on the case you would check for undefined explicitely, if it might be a real issue if somebody passes that.
You could also deside it's in the responsibility of the "somebody" to make sure not to pass bad parameters, in your case a reserved keyword.

But for the sake of an answer i'd say, yes, it can make sense, but it doesn't have to, depending on the situation and your guidelines:

```
enum DoSomething {
    DoNot= 0,
    Do = 1,
    AlsoDo = 2,
}
```